# Error when trying to install pip3 install lru-dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get this error when I try to install pip3 install lru-dict.

```
Running setup.py install for lru-dict ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for lru-dict did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\Mr. Bushido\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.╰─> lru-dict
```

I've already install Microsoft Visual C++

Comment: How are you attempting to install `lru-dict`. What python version do you have? Do you have `python2` installed in your machine as well as `python3`?

Comment: I only have python3 install and it is version 3.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `lru-dict version 1.1.8` (latest version) **does not** support `python 3.11`. What you need to do to install `lru-dict` is **downgrade** to `python 3.10`. According to `pypi` these are the supported version of python by the `lru-dict==1.1.8` module:

> - Python :: 2
> - Python :: 3
> - Python :: 3.6
> - Python :: 3.7
> - Python :: 3.8
> - Python :: 3.9
> - Python :: 3.10

You can verify that [here](https://pypi.org/project/lru-dict/1.1.8/)